# Matching values simply without using loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a table Distribution containing Amounts and Cumulative probabilities like this one :

| Amount | Cumulative probability |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.25 |
| 200 | 0.50 |
| 300 | 0.75 |

And a sample of values randomly drawn between 0 and 1 like this one :

| Draw |
| --- |
| 0.75 |
| 0.25 |
| 0.55 |
| 0.30 |

I would like to get the following table, where I retrieve the Amount corresponding to a Draw by matching loosely the Draw value and the Cumulative probability, without using loops :

| Draw | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0.75 | 300 |
| 0.25 | 100 |
| 0.55 | 200 |
| 0.30 | 100 |

I've found a solution that uses pandas DataFrame and the merge_asof function of pandas. But the code seems massive.
Besides, to use the merge_asof function, I need to sort the Draws, which I don't want at the end.

I wonder if there is a much simpler/more straightforward solution (with or without pandas).

Here is my current code :

```
distribution = pd.DataFrame({"amount": [100, 200, 300],
                             "cumulative_probability": [0.25, 0.50, 0.75]})

draw = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4), columns=["quantile"])

df_final = pd.merge_asof(draw.sort_values("quantile"), distribution,
                         left_on="quantile", right_on="cumulative_probability").sample(frac=1)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If do not want to use  merge_asof and sort, you could try to cut 0.10-1.00 as different categorical groups, suchs as 0.25-0.30 as one group, then merge tow datasets with groups.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try something like that